# Xcode Copying Main.storyboard between projects still keeps path to old project

Tags: ios, xcode8, xcode-storyboard

I copied files from one xcode old project to new project. I dragged all files from old project to new project. 
[image]
All files got transferred to new project except that the filepaths of Base.lproj and its contents LaunchScreen.storyboard and Main.storyboard  still point to the old project. Next in Xcode in my new project, I tried to open the Base.lproj and add files from the current project, but the contents of Base.lproj are grayed out. Looks like they never got copied.
I don't want the files to point to old project since I am planning to move to github and then I will have pointers to project outside local repository. 
Also my Time machine restore on my new project actually does not restore the LaunchScreen.storyboard and Main.storyboard from previous date since they were never part of my new project.

How can I correctly copy both LaunchScreen.storyboard and Main.storyboard from another project into my new project and have the file paths point to the current project 
After dragging file from old to new x-code project the full path points to new project but the Dev Region still points to old project. How to make the Dev Region point to current project?
[image]

Comment: dragged the files from one xcode project to another one at a time. In options I selected create groups instead of folder references. Now both files show up in new project but there is inconsistency (1) The LaunchScreen.storyboard Full path and dev region both point to current project path (2) The Main.storyboard Full path points to current project but the dev region still points to old project. How to fix this?

Comment: updated the original post